How to update url alias of a node and all its translations programmatically
I have a list of nodes and I want to update the url alias of these nodes and all its translations programmatically.
I am doing something like the following
function my_module_custom_update_9001() {
  $node_ids = [4931,4933,4936,5398,5399,6137,5958,4927];

  $language_manager = \Drupal::service('language_manager');
  $languages = $language_manager->getLanguages();


  foreach ($node_ids as $node_id) {
    foreach ($languages as $language) {
      // Load the node for the specific language.
      $node = Node::load($node_id);
      if ($node && $node->hasTranslation($language->getId())) {
        $node_translation = $node->getTranslation($language->getId());

        // Load the existing alias for the node translation.
        $path_alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath(['source' => '/node/' . $node_id, 'langcode' => $language->getId()]);
        if ($path_alias) {
          // Append '-old' to the alias.
          $new_alias = $path_alias->getAlias() . '-old';
          $path_alias->setAlias($new_alias);
          $path_alias->setOption('entity_update_redirects', FALSE); // Disable redirect creation
          $path_alias->save();
          \Drupal::logger('custom_alias_updater')->info('Alias for node ' . $node_id . ' in language ' . $language->getId() . ' updated to ' . $new_alias);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I managed to get this working with the following code
<?php

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\path_alias\Entity\PathAlias;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;

/**
 * Update the urls of the existing resource listing pages.
 */
function my_module_update_9001() {
  $node_ids = [4931,4933,4936,5398,5399,6137,5958,4927];

  foreach ($node_ids as $node_id) {
      // Load the node for the specific language.
      $node = Node::load($node_id);
      if ($node) {
        $languages = $node->getTranslationLanguages();
        foreach ($languages as $id => $language) {
          // Load the existing alias for the node translation.
          $path_alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'. $node_id, $language->getId());
          if ($path_alias) {
            // Append '-old' to the alias.
            $new_alias = $path_alias . '-old';
            alias_replace('/node/'. $node_id, $language->getId(), $new_alias);
            \Drupal::logger('my_module')->info($path_alias);
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

/**
 * Handler function to replace path alias with appended apth
 */
function alias_replace($path, $lang, $new_alias) {

  $path_alias_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('path_alias');

  $alias_objects = $path_alias_manager->loadByProperties([
    'path'     => $path,
    'langcode' => $lang
  ]);

  foreach($alias_objects as $alias_object) {
    $alias_object->alias = $new_alias;
    $alias_object->save();
  }
}

